# In Grub menu the internal keyboard isn't working but usb/external keyboard is working fine

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, keyboard

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my Asus laptop (dual boot with Windows 10). Everything was good. After restarting the laptop in Grub menu the internal keyboard doesn't work. However, when I plug in an USB external keyboard at Grub menu, my internal keyboard starts working. Otherwise, both keyboards always work fine in both OS. It's only in Grub menu that the internal keyboard isn't responding until connecting the USB keyboard.

Comment: You can try with Ubuntu **16.04.1** LTS downloaded from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/; it has another kernel (than 16.04.3 which I think you have now) and other hardware drivers. Otherwise you can try Ubuntu 17.10 but it has a short life (only 9 months) and is not as debugged and polished as 16.04 LTS.

Comment: already tried those. the problem exists still now

Comment: Did you try Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, the **first** point release with the xenial kernel series 4.4)? If still no go, maybe you have to try some other linux distro, that is using other kernel series than Ubuntu. You find them at http://distrowatch.com/; If you find one, where the grub menu works, you can install it (triple boot with Ubuntu and Windows) and select Ubuntu from that grub menu.